# Do you have any Asus EPU Engine details?

Tags: motherboard, power-management

I have just bought on an online shop a new mainboard from Asus that has **EPU-4 Engine** technology.

I have found only this [page](http://event.asus.com/mb/EPU-4_Engine/) that describe the concept, but I was not able to find additional details.

Do you have any more info? Do you now if it should work only with the new **ATI 4770 HD** that is not mentioned in the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have one of that EPU-4 capable ASUS motherboards in the "playroom", coupled with an MSI-8800GTS. According to the Asus EPU-4 utility, it *is* achieving power savings at time when we are not fragging our lives away over CoD 4. :)

[image]

Without a power measurer, it's hard for me to determine if there are actual power savings, but the EPU-4 utility does function similarly to an automatic over/down-clocking software.

Also, it's just ASUS marketing FUD that says only ASUS branded graphics card can benefit from EPU-4 - any graphic card should be able to benefit from it. ASUS is just saying that they tested their OWN cards to confirm support with EPU-4.